# called the javascript function onload and on button click?

Tags: javascript, button, onload

i found this javascript is called by  a button
but i want it to be onload at the same time , when button click it will call this javscript as well
 but i not sure how? hopefully anyone of you can help out

```
 function AddFileUpload()
        {
             var div = document.createElement('DIV');
             div.innerHTML = '<input id="file' + counter + '" name = "file' + counter + '" type="file" /><input id="Button' + counter + '" type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveFileUpload(this)" />';
             document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").appendChild(div);
             counter++;
        }
```

Comment: Might be useful to see your onClick Listener to figure out what's going on/wrong.

Comment: Note that the solidus `/>` is most probably incorrect. Just omit that additional slash. This is most probably *not* the cause of your original problem, though. I suggest to use FireBug or any similar debugger to see what's going wrong (perhaps there is no `FileUploadContainer` element or `counter` is not defined ....).

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onload="AddFileUpload();">
```

Comment: If that doesn't work then I bet you have some other problem with your code. Try adding an `alert("AddFileUpload called");` at the beginning of your function as a simple debugging method.

Answer (score 1):

You can call javascript on load using jquery.

$(document).ready(function() {
 var div = document.createElement('DIV');
             div.innerHTML = '';
             document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").appendChild(div);
             counter++;
});

Comment: somewhat overkill to use JQuery for such a simple task.

Comment: i try but dont know why it dont anything

Comment: you can also put your code in this section
$(function() {
 // Handler for .ready() called.
});

Comment: whic jquery js file are you refering

Comment: add this in head   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>.

Comment: can you give me your code? I will solve it. past your code in Comment.

Comment: or come to chat we will discuss there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7276/discussion-between-ashfaq-shaikh-and-actking)